# Django form input field styling

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have redefined form for contact us page, It's standard `django-form` stuff, but I'm struggling to understand how can I write description inside `<inpout>` field.

To be precise I want to write `Name` inside `<input>` field, so how can I do this. I define `<input>` field like `{{ form.name }}`, so how can I define it more like `<input type="name" class="form-control" id="id_name" placeholder="Your Name">`.

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4">
       {% if form.errors %}
           <p style="color: red">
               Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
           </p>
       {% endif %}

            <form class="form-horizontal" action="." method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="field form-group">
                    {{ form.name.errors }}                        
                    <label for="id_name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">    
                        {{form.name}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field form-group">
                    {{ form.email.errors }}                        
                    <label for="id_email" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form.email }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field form-group">
                    {{ form.phone_number.errors }}                        
                    <label for="id_phone_number" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form.phone_number }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field form-group">
                    {{ form.message.errors }}                        
                    <label for="id_message" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form.message }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div><!--/end form colon -->
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401025/define-css-class-in-django-forms) should help.

Comment: You can also use the styling in a script: $('#id_form.message').addClass()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[If you want to modify the placeholder text, or other values of the field Django creates, it can be done in the form code using the widget's `attrs`:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'my-class',
                'placeholder': 'Name goes here',
            }))
```

If your intention is to keep all of the code in the template you will have to manually create each input field instead of using the ones Django renders. [You can still access the values of the generated field in the template to help you do that though.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#attributes-of-boundfield)

```
<input name="{{ form.name.name }}" type="text" placeholder="Name field">
```

Comment: This is a nice example, I have missed this in docs, but I would like that `placeholder` live inside `django-templates` not `django-forms`.