# How can I style django forms with bootstrap CSS?

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-4

I've written a form class in django, and while trying to output it, found that it is not beautiful to look at.

```
class AddAppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    docchoices = []
    for doc in doctor.objects.all():
        docst = [doc.docid, doc.name]
        docchoices.append(docst)
    # CHOICES = [('select1', 'select 1'),
    #            ('select2', 'select 2')]
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=[('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female')]
    )
    age = forms.IntegerField(max_value=100,min_value=1, required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone', max_length=14, required=True)
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', max_length=25, required=False)
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address', max_length=60, required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(label='City', max_length=20, required=False)
    doctors = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=docchoices,
    )

{# Load the tag library #} {% extends "appointments/base.html" %} {% block title %}Create appointment{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" action="/appointments/appointmentcreated" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-6">
                <label for="Name">Name</label> {{ form.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-2 ">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Age</span> {{ form.age }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Gender</span> {{ form.gender }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-2 ">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email">Phone
                <span class="text-muted">(Required)</span>
            </label> {{ form.phone }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-2 ">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email">Email
                <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span>
</label> {{ form.email }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="address">Address</label> {{ form.address }}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-6">
                <label for="city">City</label> {{ form.city }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-6">
                <label for="sel_doctor">Select Doctor</label> {{ form.doctors }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Create appointment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Without bootstrap]

I attempted to style it as per the suggestions [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html). But the option attrs arent being accepted for Charfield.

```
name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100, attrs={
                       'class': 'form-control'})


File "/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    class AddAppointmentForm(forms.Form):
File "/home/joel/myappointments/appointments/forms.py", line 15, in AddAppointmentForm
    'class': 'form-control'})
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 214, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

What is the proper way to use a css framework like bootstrap with django forms?

Comment: The `docchoices` should not get updated if a new `Doctor` is created?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Didnt get you. Wouldnt that be updated at each form reload?

Comment: no the for loop is executed at the construction of the *class*, not objects of the class. That is one of the reasons why `for` loops in a class are so uncommon. The only real usecase I've seen for such `for` loops, is if you would like to construct for example a large number of (nearly) identical functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define css class in django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401025/define-css-class-in-django-forms)

Comment: There is a Django app [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It renders the form with Bootstrap (or Foundation).

Answer (score 4):

What you need is widget-tweaks.

It allows you to apply custom styles and CSS classes to django variables (which also includes form objects)

> pip install django-widget-tweaks

Then add 'widget-tweaks' to your installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'widget_tweaks',
...
]
```

Then import widget-tweaks in your template

```
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
...
```

Now suppose you want to apply class "abc" to a form element "email"

```
{{ form.email|add_class:"abc" }}
```

This will apply class "abc" to that form element. 
This is a much easier and cleaner way to apply styles to forms rather than messing with the backend code

For more info or documentation on "django-widget-tweaks" look here :

https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks