# Can you use HTML Input Tags in place of Django form templates?

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

I have had a basic login form working and styles with CSS. I have tried to update this with Tailwind to improve the design of my application. However, to apply this styling, input tags are required, is there a way to use Input tags to authenticate a user as opposed to using the form templates provided by Django? i.e: `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Unless I am reading incorrectly this won't let me use input tags and still requires {{ form.username }} for example meaning I won't be able to include the Tailwind CSS? @Chris

Comment: See lower: `form.username.label`, `form.username.id_for_label`, `form.username.value`, `form.username.help_text`, ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/401030/3787407 for how to add class attr to form element in django.